# Separating metals out of a magnet

Tags: acid-base, metal, metallurgy, rare-earth-elements

I have acquired the crushed magnet out of a motor I was given. If I'm correct that the magnet is $\ce{NdFeB}$ magnet, how could I separate out all the metals into a pure or oxide form? And for hard drive magnets, is there any way to remove the $\ce{Ni}$ coating without having to get nitric acid?  I don't have any proper chemistry equipment at all.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://www.eurare.eu/docs/eres2014/thirdSession/VenkatesanPrakash.pdf) paper,  it seems Electrochemical recovery of Neodymium is possible from the Magnet.